# Viewing Dynamic Flash website in ipad

Tags: ipad, flash

Hello people

I am really facing a big ask. I have created a dynamic AS3 flash website which loads images and text from an xml file.

Everything is fine, it works okay. EXCEPT that it goes totally dead in Ipad / iphone. My client was somehow not aware of this. And now he is going ballistic about the importance of IPAD in todays world etc etc..

I know IPAD does NOT support flash. Other than the OBVIOUS solution of recoding the complete website in HTML5 etc, I just wanted to know if somebody has tried anything else that could somehow make it work.

I have heard about the following, would like to know if any of this would make sense:

1. USE FLASH SUPPORTIVE BROwSER APPS IN IPAD

like Photon, skyfire, Puffin : are these brosers any good!! observations !!

2. CONVERT THE FLASH FILE INTO HTML5

using :

(1) Google SWiffy

Tried converting flash to HTML5 using swiffy extension for flash professional cs5 but the output was a disaster. XMLlist ignored, .... the list of errors is endless.

(2) Using Flash Professional CS6 / Toolkit for CreateJS

Any body having experience With this?? Any suggestions.

(3) Sothink sWf decompiler - decompile to HTML5

(4) Adobe Wallaby

(5) Anything else that is out there ...

3. USE ADOBE AIR

(1) Repackage as an app for IOS

This would work but can never give the experience of a website. Any thoughts.

(2) Package as AIR execute able file that can be run on IPAD??

Does Apple Ipad allow the installation of AIR files ??

Can it somehow be added to a browser and where it may automatically be loaded into the safari browser in IPAD etc ?? Its highly unlikely. Any thoughts !!

I would really appreciate if anybody and everbody could share their eperiences with these options AND whether or not its worth the try !!

Is the only option available is RECODING ONLY!!

Thanks ... looking forward to all your inputs and suggestions

Thanking you all in anticipation

Moody

Comment: You could also try using NME. Very similar to AS3 and can export to HTML5 as well as iOS, Android etc

Comment: re 3), you can package it to run on ipad (as a native application rather than AIR, but same principle) but it will be an app not a website so cant be used in a browser.

Comment: Thanks Allan... could you elaborate more on NME!! Sorry, from what i understand its different script and ill have to recode anyays right!! Am i getting it right!!.

Answer (score 0):

Like you I found swiffy a waste of time for most things other than very simple as2 animations.
I don't know about AIR, but CS6 toolkit with createjs is excellent. Have a look at the video on the adobe site (http://www.adobe.com/devnet/createjs.html) - it's a good introduction to what you can and can't do.

Pete